How do I fetch all tables from one database when I have two?
I have two databases and want to fetch all tables from only one. If I run cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master") and cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_schema") both results are the same and fetch all tables in both databases. I want to fetch only from one database.
Full code:
import sqlite3

while  True:
      con=sqlite3.connect("Nested_Database_try")
      cur=con.cursor()
      Mcon=sqlite3.connect("Master_Database_try")
      Mcur=con.cursor()
      print('''            Press "1" for Creating Nested Table (Example:-  Invoice Number)
            Press "2" for Creating Master Table (Example:-  DSS Number)
                  Press "11" Insert Invoice Detail
                  Press "21" Insert Dss Detail
            Press 3 View Invoice Detail
            Press 4 View DSS Detail
            Press 5 Exit Program\n''')
      #print(strings+"\n")
      selection=int(input("Choose 1 or 2 for creating tables...   "))

      if selection==1:
                  en1=input("Type Nasted Table Name Like Invoice Number...   ")

                                                #---------This Table is use for invoice Table
                  Nasted_table=cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{}'(
                                          Product TEXT,
                                          Amount  INT,
                                          Total_amt NT
                                          );'''.format(en1))
                  print("Nested Table Create Sucessfully as Invoive number with" + en1)
                  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")

      elif  selection==11:
                  inv_no=input("Enter invoice no...   ")
                  product=input("Enter Product Name...   ")
                  amt=input("Enter product amount...   ")
                  T_amt=input("Enter Total amt...   ")

                  inset=cur.execute(" INSERT Into '{}' (Product, Amount, Total_amt) values ( '{}',  {},  {}); ".format(inv_no ,product, amt, T_amt))

                  con.commit()
                  #con.close()
                  print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n")

      elif selection==2:
                  en2=input("Type Master Table Name Like DSS Number...   ")
                  Master_table=cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{}'(
                                                                  invoice_no INT);'''.format(en2))
                  print("Master  Table  Create  Sucessfully as Invoive number with" + en2)
                  print("===============================================\n")

      elif selection==21:
                  M_inv=input("Enter Total amt...   ")
                  inset=cur.execute(" INSERT Into '{}' (Product, Amount, Total_amt) values ( {}); ".format(en2 ,M_inv))
                  Mcon.commit()
                  #Mcon.close()
                  print("************************************************************************\n")

      elif selection==3:
                  inv_rec=input("Enter Table / Invoice name...   ")    #---- cur.execute(''' Select name  from sql_master''')
                  View_Invoice_Detail=cur.execute("SELECT * FROM '{}'; ".format(inv_rec))
                  for items in View_Invoice_Detail:
                              print(items)

                  con.commit()
                  #con.close()
                  print("______________________________________________\n")

      elif selection==4:
                  View_DSS_Detail=cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master") #---working
                  View_DSS_Detail=cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_schema") #--same working as above

                  for itemss in View_DSS_Detail:
                              print(itemss)

                  Mcon.commit()
                  #Mcon.close()

      elif selection==5:
                  print("Programe closed")
                  break

I want to fetch all tables only from one specific database.

"...  both results are the same and fetch all tables in both databases." You insert everything into one database. Cursor relates to 1st database but is used when you intend to address the 2nd database too. The same cursor is assigned to another variable again (Mcur), but never used. Seems Mcur = Mcon.cursor(), then Mcur.execute() was intended for 2nd database.

sqlite_master and sqlite_schema are the same table. The name sqlite_master is for backward compatibility.
